# matcovnet pooling_cup.cpp pooling_backward_cpu function parameters

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, matconvnet, max-pooling

Hi I am trying to write a new pooling layer in matcovnet. I tried with Matlab code but it is way too much slow, so now I am trying to implement with cpp code. I am trying to use pooling_cup.cpp code to implement my work. But I am confused with parameters of pooling_backward_cpu function -

`pooling_backward_cpu(type* derData,
                     type const* data,
                     type const* derPooled,
                     size_t width, size_t height, size_t depth,
                     size_t windowWidth, size_t windowHeight,type const* a,
                     size_t strideX, size_t strideY,
                     size_t padLeft, size_t padRight, size_t padTop, size_t 
    padBottom)`

Now what does - `type* derData,
                     type const* data,
                     type const* derPooled` 
mean ?